# JWT token verification procedure to obtain the user object

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

In my current test node express project, I use JWT. For a POST route, I need the user who fires the request. Therefore I send the JWT with the request. In the NodeJs controller, I have access to the supplied token.

I decode this and then have the user email, exp and iat. Is it now correct that I only start a DB query with the decoded email of the user, with which I receive the user object?

Or do I have to do another validation step? I don't miss any other validation but I find it somehow unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

> I decode this and then have the user email, exp and iat. Is it now correct that I only start a DB query with the decoded email of the user, with which I receive the user object?

You can use the email from the decoded JWT token only after its validation. Once you validate it, you know that user information is legitimate unless your secret is compromised.

You need to use an auth middleware that will allow the request to access the next middleware and the controller logic.

> Or do I have to do another validation step? I don't miss any other validation but I find it somehow unsafe.

If the encoded JWT token is validated correctly, you don't need to add any validation for decoded data, however, it is important to validate the data coming in the request (You can use [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi)).